# How to create a package using the browser in Pharo?

Tags: pharo

For a newbie in Pharo, how to create a package? The [MOOC exercise](http://rmod-pharo-mooc.lille.inria.fr/OOPMooc/Exercises/Exercise-Counter.pdf) says "Using the Browser create a package," but how?

Answer (score 6):

You'll find an answer at [3.2 Creating a new Package in Pharo by Example](http://books.pharo.org/updated-pharo-by-example/pdf/2018-09-29-UpdatedPharoByExample.pdf#page=50):

> From the World menu, open a **System Browser**. Right-click on an existing
>   package in the Package pane and select `Add package...` from the menu.

However, the tools change frequently. It's sometimes **New package**. Here's what it looks like (today) in three different versions of Pharo:

### Pharo 8

[image: Creating a new package in Pharo 8]

### Pharo 7

[image: Creating a new package in Pharo 7]

### Pharo 6

To open Nautilus, you have to left-click first, then choose **System Browser**:

[image: Creating a new package in Pharo 6]

Answer (score 2):

And the classical way is to just define a new class and type in the package name you want in the definition.